# How can i turn python to apk?

Tags: python, android, apk

I am just a newbie on that things and I want to turn python to apk with android studio or whatever. I don't really need anything to complex, I just want to open my codes output gui (I used turtle) when I open the app. Nothing else, thats all. It is probably complex process so you can just give me where to look and learn if you can't explain it all in here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turtle is built around TKinter, which is a library for making desktop apps. There [doesn't seem to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63294290/6335363) a way to run programs built in TKinter within Android without using some other app to run them. If you're ok with that, then you could use the solution suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64725622/6335363) to run your code by pasting it into an app that can run Python code.